# How to get function to run after previous function has executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

So I have been working on a website what gets some information from a google sheet cell and it uses that to color a google maps overlay. The problem i'm running into is that the map overlay seems to be running before the cell information is retrieved. I'm not sure how to get the map overlay to wait until it has the info it needs.

Ultimately i'm going to have to get multiple cell values so I don't want to call my map every time I run getCell() hence me not putting myMap() inside the done() of $.getJSON

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<script>
  /** This is the ID of the google sheet **/

  //This is the google sheet ID of the google sheet with the graphs for the event.
  var theSheetID = "1eAP6dugifHIHRSgnc8Mx-FdzriDBP5r0vn8yq0ShknA";

  var typeOfEvent = "Event";
  var eventManager = "Jeb";
  var managerCell = "123-456-789";

  //This is the google sheet ID of the google sheet with the lot values for the event.
  var theMapSheetID = "1oUW8EvxlSMArW1qTQMxVJua1QrgCOgo5G545Jb4OZ-4";
  var workSheetID = "default";

  //duplicate these for every cell you are want to access
  var theRow = "1";
  var theColumn = "1";


  //make duplicates of this variable for each lot you have
  //i.e. lot
  var theLot;

  var theLot1;

  //theLot=20;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    getCell = function() {
      var api = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/';
      var spreadsheet = theMapSheetID;
      var worksheet = workSheetID;

      var row = theRow;
      var col = theColumn;

      var row1 = 2;
      var col2 = 2;

      var url = api + spreadsheet + '/' + worksheet + '/public/basic/R' + row + 'C' + col + '?alt=json';

      $.getJSON(url)
        .done(function(data) {

          console.log(data)

          if (data.entry) {

            theLot = parseInt(data.entry.content['$t']);
            // return $.Deferred();
            //myMap();

          } else {}
        })
        .fail(function() {});
    }
    //$.when(getCell()).then(myMap());
    //myMap();

  });
</script>

<script>
  function myMap() {
    //theLot = 15;
    var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.051651, -75.515626);
    var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.048082, -75.521755);
    var p3 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.048006, -75.522286);
    var p4 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.051565, -75.5288822);
    var p5 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.056059, -75.523349);
    var p6 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.053316, -75.520697);





    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
    var mapOptions = {
      center: p2,
      zoom: 15
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    //      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);

    var theColor;

    //alert(theLot);

    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.051629, -75.522953);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myCenter
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: theLot.toString()
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);




    if (theLot < 25) {
      theColor = "#ff0000";
    } else if (theLot > 25 && theLot < 50) {
      theColor = "#fff200";
    } else if (theLot > 50 && theLot < 75) {
      theColor = "#aaff00";
    } else {
      theColor = "#00ff00";
    }

    var lotOverlay = new google.maps.Polygon({
      path: [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6],
      strokeColor: "#000000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,

      
      fillColor: theColor,

      
      fillOpacity: 0.5
    });

    lotOverlay.setMap(map);
  }
</script>


<body>

  <br />
  <br />

  <div class="container">
    
  </div>

  <br />

  <div class="container" style="text-align:center; max-width: 42em;">
    <div class="jumbotron">

      <!-- Event Name -->
      <div align="center">

        <h2>Graduation 2017</h2>

        <h4>Please contact us for more detailed information:</h4>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.write("<h4>" + typeOfEvent + " Manager: " + eventManager + "</h4><br />");

          document.write(" <div class=\"row\"> <a href=\"tel:" + managerCell + "\" class=\"btn-primary btn-lg btn-success\">Call</a> &nbsp <a href=\"sms:" + managerCell + "\" class=\"btn-primary btn-lg btn-info\">Text</a></div>");
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Link to ELP -->
    <a href="ELP/ELP.pdf" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">View Event Logistics Plan (ELP)</a>

  </div>

  <hr width="100%" size="3" color="#0000FF" />

  <div class="container" align="Center">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <!-- Google Sheet Overview -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.write("<iframe src=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + theSheetID + "/pubchart?oid=784983700&amp;format=interactive&chrome=false\"  width=\"600\"  height =\"400\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>");
        </script>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <!-- Google Sheet Flow -->
        <script>
          document.write("<iframe src=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + theSheetID + "/pubhtml?gid=225087979&amp;single=true&amp;headers=false&chrome=false\" width=\"600\"  height =\"400\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>");
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <!-- Google Sheet Deatils -->

        <script>
          document.write("<iframe src=\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + theSheetID + "/pubhtml?gid=328375376&gridlines=false&range=a1:l20&chrome=false\" width = \"1000\" height =\"600\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>");
        </script>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div id="map" style="width:80%;height:500px"></div>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBfWJMAiVJy9LcuMF_vogE_KawTRFaFxig&callback=myMap"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <br />
  <br />



</body>





</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to call myMap() after your ajax call is successful?

Comment: place your myMap() inside the done() of $.getJSON

Comment: Yeah, I want to call myMap() after getCell() successfully runs

Comment: You can place your myMap() inside the .done(){ myMap()} of $.getJson. that will call the myMap(). check if (data.entry) is true if it's not calling myMap()

Comment: The only reason I don't want to do that is because I want to run getCell() multiple times to get the values of multiple cells. I don't want issues to arise because myMap() is getting called multiple times.

Comment: You need to use jquery deferred then. can you show how you are going to call your getCell()

Comment: i ideally want to call getCell() like this: var theValue = getCell(1,1);

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript statements are executed line by line. However, with effects, the next line of code can be run even though the effect is not finished. This can create errors.

To prevent this, you can create a callback function. All it is, you can pass the function as an argument and it will be executed last.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow", function(){
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
    });
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

if you gonna call it like that, then you can get an alert before hide is finished executing.

```
 $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide("slow");
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
  });
```

Comment: Show a simple example of a callback function here, rather than just linking to w3schools...

Comment: I saw that same code on w3schools, the problem is i'm still confused by it.

Comment: OK, in this example,  when a user clicks the button, hide functions is executed with "slow" parameter, and then another function will be called, that is passed in as an argument. This way, function execution is chained, so one function will be called after another in guaranteed sequence.